# Added \ in JSONObject Strings

Tags: android, json

I have \ in my JSONObject as shown below:

```
{"coord":[{"lat":"[\"0\"","lng":"\"0\""}],...
```

I am trying to rid of the \s as shown below:

```
{"coord":[{"lat":"0","lng":"0"}],...
```

In an attempt to rid of the \s I added .replaceAll("\\\\", "") which I have seen on other SO questions as answers to this issue, but .replaceAll("\\\\", ""); is not working. Any suggestions?

```
GPS gps = new GPS(getApplicationContext());
               double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
               double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
JSONArray coord = new JSONArray();

               String lattostring = String.valueOf(latitude);

               Log.v("lattostring", lattostring);

               String lontostring = String.valueOf(longitude);
               Log.v("lontostring", lontostring);
               JSONObject latObject = new JSONObject();

               String jsonFormattedlat = lattostring.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
               String jsonFormattedlon = lontostring.replaceAll("\\\\", "");


               Log.v("jsonFormattedlat", jsonFormattedlat);
               Log.v("jsonFormattedlom", jsonFormattedlon);

               coord.put(jsonFormattedlat);
               Log.v("coord1", String.valueOf(coord.put(jsonFormattedlat)));
               coord.put(jsonFormattedlon);
              coord.put(lontostring);
               Log.v("coord2", String.valueOf(coord.put(jsonFormattedlon)));


               coord.toString().replace( "\\\"", "");
               conn.addValuePair("coord", coord.toString().replace( "\\\"", ""));
               Log.v("coord", coord.toString().replace( "\\\"", ""));
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use JSONTokener http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html -- according to the docs "Parses a JSON (RFC 4627) encoded string into the corresponding object." And the examples it uses shows similar \ backslashes to yours. Let me know if this works.

Comment: The real question here is how did the `\\` come in in the first place. This is the point where it should be repaired, not a workaround after the error happened.

Comment: You can't simply replace them... `"[\"0\"","lng":"\"0\""` is a single value. You are trying to turn that into a value and other key-value pair. I would fix wherever that data came from initially

Comment: @cricket_007 I am trying to format something like this: {"coord":[{"lat":"0","lng":"0"}],... Any suggestions, please?

Comment: @njachowski I do not think JSONTokener will do. Please look at the JSON I want to receive.

Comment: `String.valueOf(latitude)` returns a number as a string... why are you even trying to string replace backslashes on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, `"[\"0\"","lng":"\"0\""` is a single value for the key `"lat"`, so the problem is not that the quotes are escaped, but that you seem to be "putting" values into JSON incorrectly.

This code gets the format that you wish.

```
// make containing object
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

// get your values
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
// make array
JSONArray coord = new JSONArray();

// object to put in array
JSONObject coord1 = new JSONObject();
coord1.put("lat", latitude);
coord1.put("lng", longitude);
// put object in array
coord.put(coord1);

// put array in containing object
json.put("coord", coord);

System.out.println(json.toString());
// {"coord":[{"lng":0,"lat":0}]}
```

Comment: json is {"coord":[{"lng":0,"lat":0}]}, but the response back after adding the value pair with http post is:  {"coord":[{"lat":"{\"coord\":[{\"lng\":0","lng":"\"lat\":0}]}"}],...

Comment: Your question said nothing about an HTTP POST, so I can't help you with that. You are welcome to create a new question asking about that, but since I seemed to have solved this question, you are welcome to accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

should work:

```
 str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

and for single replace this will do:

```
str = str.replace("\\", "");
```